# Fatal error: __autoload() is no longer supported, use spl_autoload_register() instead in /home/storage/736/3736736/user/htdocs/wp-includes/compat.php

Tags: php, wordpress, fatal-error, autoload, spl-autoloader

My wordpress website is getting the below error:

> Fatal error: __autoload() is no longer supported, use spl_autoload_register() instead in /home/storage/736/3736736/user/htdocs/wp-includes/compat.php on line 502

From review of other tickets I updated line 502 with:

```
function spl_autoload_register( $classname ) {
    ...
}
```

However I now get the below error:

> Warning: Private methods cannot be final as they are never overridden by other classes in /home/storage/736/3736736/user/htdocs/wp-includes/class-wp-session-tokens.php on line 71
>
> Deprecated: Required parameter $tt_id follows optional parameter $object_id in /home/storage/736/3736736/user/htdocs/wp-includes/nav-menu.php on line 931
>
> Deprecated: Required parameter $taxonomy follows optional parameter $object_id in /home/storage/736/3736736/user/htdocs/wp-includes/nav-menu.php on line 931
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function create_function() in /home/storage/736/3736736/user/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/LayerSlider/layerslider.php:69 Stack trace: #0 /home/storage/736/3736736/user/htdocs/wp-settings.php(303): include_once() #1 /home/storage/736/3736736/user/htdocs/wp-config.php(81): require_once('/home/storage/7...') #2 /home/storage/736/3736736/user/htdocs/wp-load.php(37): require_once('/home/storage/7...') #3 /home/storage/736/3736736/user/htdocs/wp-blog-header.php(13): require_once('/home/storage/7...') #4 /home/storage/736/3736736/user/htdocs/index.php(17): require('/home/storage/7...') #5 {main} thrown in /home/storage/736/3736736/user/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/LayerSlider/layerslider.php on line 69

I am using WordPress.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Sounds like you just updated from PHP 7 to PHP 8 but you're still using a really old version of WordPress. The obvious solution is to update WordPress.

Comment: the website is running PHP Version 8.0.26

Comment: Is it possible to to check when from logs when the PHP update may have happen?

Comment: Also, is it possible to update WordPress via FTP without losing my existing content?

Comment: https://blog.hubspot.com/website/update-wordpress

Answer (score 1):

You may face an issue with your PHP version. I also faced the same issue. My website was not compatible with the latest PHP version. I changed the PHP version to 7.4 and it works for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).